# How to check a feature-gate state in GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

How to check a feature-gate state in GKE. The closes thing I found was doing:

`kubectl cluster-info dump | grep feature-gate`

but this only shows the flags of the nodes, not the master. Are they the same?

The reason I'm asking is the following: It's not very clear if `CustomResourcesSubresources` feature-gate is now **beta** or **alpha** and enabled by default or not. I’m confused as the PR here ( https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/62786 ) seems like it is *beta since 1.11*, but the documentation states ( https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/ ) that it’s still *alpha and disabled by default* (edited)

Answer (score 1):

Masters are the same except it are managed by Google. The links you posted are Kubernetes specific.

Since there is no direct way to check for feature-gate states other than the method you shown, I went ahead and created a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122712579) to better handle that situation. You may also add further information in the thread.